# Method inheritance in the JavaScript prototype chain

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

"*In javascript, every object has a secret link to the object which created it,forming a chain. When an object is asked for a property that it does not have,its parent object is asked... continually up the chain until the property is found or until the root object is reached.*"

All , I always think the above words is truth even now, So I did some test to verify it , I intended to define the relationship of objects like below. please review it .

[image]

The code should look like below .

```
        //Shape - superclass
        function Shape() {
          this.x = 0;
          this.y = 0;
        };

        Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;

            alert('Shape move');
        };

        // Rectangle - subclass
        function Rectangle() {
          Shape.call(this); //call super constructor.
        }

        Rectangle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;

            alert('Rectangle move');
        };

        // Square - subclass
        function Square(){
            Shape.call(this);
        }

        Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
        Square.prototype=Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);

        var rect = new Rectangle();

        var sq= new Square();

        sq.x=1;
        sq.y=1;
        sq.move(1,1);
```

Since the `move` method can't be found in the `Square.prototype`, So JavaScript will find it in its parent objects following the chain, I had thought It will be found in the `Rectangle.prototype`, but actually it is found in the root `Shape.prototype` , So What I can't understand is why `sq.move(1,1)` actually call the `Shape.prototype.move` instead of calling the `move` method of `Rectangle.prototype` ? Did I missed something ?thanks.

Comment: Should the `Square()` contructor call `Rectangle()` rather than `Shape()`?

Comment: Because `Square` is a `Shape` subclass instead a `Rectangle` subclass (?)

Comment: @All Let me try it , I think it is not the problem.

Comment: Isn't `Retangle.prototype = new Shape()` easier that using `Object.create()`?

Comment: @All , The `call` method is just invoke the `constructor`, it doesn't matter with the `prototype` object. BTW, normally the inheritance chain is always about the `prototype` of object. `constructor` is only used to construct the object created.

Comment: @Jack +1 Right , Both of them are ok. It depends you code style.

Comment: Then what you have is a `Superclass - Shape() => Subclass - Rectangle() => Subclass of a subclass - Square()` ?

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX yes , right .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just overwritten your `Rectangle.prototype` which already had `move`. Since you have overwritten it, the `move` you attached is no longer there, that's why `Shape`'s move is used.

```
Rectangle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  alert('Rectangle move');
};

function Square(){
  Shape.call(this);
}

//overwritten the prototype
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
```

Create the prototype object first, before adding to it.

```
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.move = function (x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  alert('Rectangle move');
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with hoisting; the code is simply overwriting `Rectangle.prototype` :)

Comment: @Jack Oh yeah. His code was so mixed, that I initially thought it was. Thanks

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Now I know the reason ! `Object.create` will assign another instance to the `Rectangle.prototype`, So In my code , there doesn't exist the `move` method any more in the `Rectangle.prototype`, Because there is another object override the before one . Hope you verify my understanding . Thanks.

Comment: override ----> overwrite sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Move you extension of prototype down.
Now you are assigning prototype after extending it , so it will overwrite the extended one

```
//Shape - superclass
        function Shape() {
          this.x = 0;
          this.y = 0;
        };
        // Rectangle - subclass
        function Rectangle() {
          Shape.call(this); //call super constructor.
        }
        // Square - subclass
        function Square(){
            Shape.call(this);
        }    

        Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
        Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);

        Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;

            alert('Shape move');
        };
        Rectangle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;

            alert('Rectangle move');
        };

        var rect = new Rectangle();
        var sq = new Square();

        sq.x=1;
        sq.y=1;
        sq.move(1,1);
```